# Only allow access to list items, not any other library pages (e.g. forms pages)

Tags: permissions

How can I allow users in a certain group to view/open files from a document library but not access any other part of the library like views?

My document library contains html files, which users can view/open (via a direct link), however I do not want them to see any other part of the library. E.g. they should not be able to have an overview of all the items in the document library.

How can I achive this? (I'm using SharePoint 2010)

Answer (score 1):

You can create two folders in the library and put html files inside one and other files inside other folder. Then break the permissions of the folders. Give the group read acess to the folder which contains html files. Give appropriate permissions to other folder. And finally you can choose to show flat structure of files in the view. Users will be able to see only those files on which they have permissions.  The only thing to be taken care of is to upload files in folders and not at root of the library.